# Accedently substituted my clash of clans village with a new one while trying to connect. How do i get my old village back?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I factory reset my mobile phone so it deleted everything and when I downloaded Clash of Clans I found that my village wasn't there. After that, I accidentally substituted it with a new one. How can i get my old village back?

Comment: Are you on Android or iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done so already, you log into your iOS Game Center account or your Google Play account. The game will then normally ask you if you want to reload the village on the phone.